# Saving GUI entries to a text file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, text, save

This is the first time I've used tkinter and GUI in Python, so I'm pretty much a novice.

I have a big GUI form that I made with tkinter. It uses all the classic tkinter widgets: text entry boxes, spinboxes, option menus, radio buttons, and check buttons. What I want to do is let a user enter data into the GUI form and then press the Save button to save everything to a text file. Unfortunately, I can't find many examples of saving data like this to a text file. Here is a generic sample of my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

variables = dict()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Generic Form')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

ttk.Label(root, text='Generic Form', font=("TkDefaultFont", 16)).grid()

drf = ttk.Frame(root)
drf.grid(padx=10, sticky=(tk.N + tk.S))
drf.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

g_info = ttk.LabelFrame(drf, text='Generic Data')
g_info.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['Scenario ID'] = tk.StringVar()
ttk.Label(g_info, text='Scenario ID').grid(row=0, column=0)
ttk.Entry(g_info, textvariable=variables['Scenario ID']).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['Integer Value'] = tk.IntVar()
ttk.Label(g_info, text='Integer Value').grid(row=2, column=0)
ttk.Spinbox(g_info, textvariable=variables['Integer Value'], from_=0, to=100, increment = 1).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['OPTIONS'] = tk.StringVar()
option_var = tk.StringVar(value='Choose')
choices = ('This', 'That', 'The Other Thing')
ttk.Label(g_info, text='OPTIONS').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
ttk.OptionMenu(g_info, option_var, *choices).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

choice_default = tk.StringVar(value=F)
variables['CHOICE'] = tk.StringVar()
choice_frame = ttk.Frame(g_info)
ttk.Label(g_info, text='CHOICE').grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
choice_frame.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
for choice in ('T', 'F'):
    ttk.Radiobutton(choice_frame, value=choice, test=choice, variable=choice_default.pack()

buttons = tk.Frame(drf)
buttons.grid(column=1, pady=20, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
save_button = ttk.Button(buttons, test='Save')
save_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

def on_save():
   filename = f'C:/test.txt'
   data = dict()
   with open(filename, 'w', newline='' as fh:
      fh.write("\n")

save_button.configure(command=on_save)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the output text I'm trying to get.

```
Generic Data
  Scenario ID = Scenario 1
  Integer Value = 51
  Options = The Other Thing
  Choice = T
```

Most of what I know with tkinter is from the book *Python GUI Programming with Tkinter* by Alan D. Moore. Unfortuantely, this book only describes how to save data into a CSV file. For the project I'm working on, I need it saved in a text file. I know there's a way to do this, but I can't find any examples except for the Entry widget.

Comment: Do you know how to add a callback to the button (which I don't see here) with `command=`?  In that case, it's just a matter of fetching the values with `variables[xxx].get()` and writing them like any other file.  Thre's nothing magic here.

Comment: Note that CSV is also a text file.  I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: My problem is that when I try to save the GUI form in txt format rather than csv, all I get is a blank text file.

Comment: Please show us the code that you've tried.

Comment: Um, the code I've tried is right above.

Comment: There is no code on saving to file in your posted code.

Comment: I just edited the code with the save button code I was using. I originally did not include it because I was obviously doing something wrong with it.

Comment: You just open a file and then write a newline to it only.

Comment: Isn't that what I have in the code? I opened a new file and wrote a new line to it.

Comment: I means that is why  you get a blank file.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for help! What do you not understand about this? I am trying to save to entries to a text file. Why can't anyone here help me without being an insulting snob?

Comment: No one has been an insulting snob to you.  You're getting free, qualified advice from competent engineers.  If you can't participate here without taking things overly personally, then maybe this is not the right place for you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After some trial and error, I have finally found a solution and can post an answer. Let me be clear though: this answer is due in no part to anyone who replied to this post. I stated upfront that I am new to tkinter, but everyone that replied (acw1668, Rory, Brian Oakley, and especially Tim Roberts) treated me as if I was a buffoon. You all talked past the issue, would only give me the vaguest hints about what I was doing wrong, and offered me no solutions. Thanks for nothing everyone. You have my deepest condescension, because that is all you gave me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

variables = dict()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Generic Form')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

ttk.Label(root, text='Generic Form', font=("TkDefaultFont", 16)).grid()

drf = ttk.Frame(root)
drf.grid(padx=10, sticky=(tk.N + tk.S))
drf.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame_info = ttk.LabelFrame(drf, text='Generic Data')
frame_info.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['Scenario ID'] = tk.StringVar()
ttk.Label(frame_info, text='Scenario ID').grid(row=0, column=0)
ttk.Entry(frame_info, textvariable=variables['Scenario ID']).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['Integer Value'] = tk.IntVar()
ttk.Label(frame_info, text='Integer Value').grid(row=2, column=0)
ttk.Spinbox(frame_info, textvariable=variables['Integer Value'], from_=0, to=100, increment = 1).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['OPTIONS'] = tk.StringVar()
option_var = tk.StringVar(value='Choose')
choices = ('Choose', 'This', 'That', 'The Other Thing')
ttk.Label(frame_info, text='OPTIONS').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
ttk.OptionMenu(g_info, variables['OPTIONS'], *choices).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

choice_default = tk.StringVar(value='F')
variables['CHOICE'] = tk.StringVar()
choice_frame = ttk.Frame(frame_info)
ttk.Label(frame_info, text='CHOICE').grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
choice_frame.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
for choice in ('T', 'F'):
    ttk.Radiobutton(choice_frame, value=choice, variable=variables['CHOICE']).pack()

def on_save():
    
    
    inc = variables['Scenario ID'].get()
    number = variables['Integer Value'].get()
    menu = variables['OPTIONS'].get()
    boolean = variables['CHOICE'].get()
    
    with open('GUI.txt', 'w') as x:
        x.write( 'Generic Data' ), x.write('\n')
        x.write( f'  Scenario ID = {inc}' ), x.write('\n')
        x.write( f'  Integer Value = {number}' ), x.write('\n')
        x.write( f'  Options = {menu}' ), x.write('\n')
        x.write( f'  Choice = {boolean}' ), x.write('\n')

tk.Button(frame_info, text='Save', command=on_save).grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your complaints would be easier to believe if your code didn't look just like mine.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes one or two typos in your code, and adds a "Save" button which writes the values to the console.  Writing it to a text file is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

variables = dict()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Generic Form')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

ttk.Label(root, text='Generic Form', font=("TkDefaultFont", 16)).grid()

drf = ttk.Frame(root)
drf.grid(padx=10, sticky=(tk.N + tk.S))
drf.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

g_info = ttk.LabelFrame(drf, text='Generic Data')
g_info.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['Scenario ID'] = tk.StringVar()
ttk.Label(g_info, text='Scenario ID').grid(row=0, column=0)
ttk.Entry(g_info, textvariable=variables['Scenario ID']).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['Integer Value'] = tk.IntVar()
ttk.Label(g_info, text='Integer Value').grid(row=2, column=0)
ttk.Spinbox(g_info, textvariable=variables['Integer Value'], from_=0, to=100, increment = 1).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

variables['OPTIONS'] = tk.StringVar()
option_var = tk.StringVar(value='Choose')
choices = ('This', 'That', 'The Other Thing')
ttk.Label(g_info, text='OPTIONS').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
ttk.OptionMenu(g_info, option_var, *choices).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

choice_default = tk.StringVar(value='F')
variables['CHOICE'] = tk.StringVar()
choice_frame = ttk.Frame(g_info)
ttk.Label(g_info, text='CHOCE').grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
choice_frame.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
for choice in 'TF':
    ttk.Radiobutton(choice_frame, value=choice, variable=choice_default).pack()

def save():
    scen = variables['Scenario ID'].get()
    intval = variables['Integer Value'].get()
    opt = variables['OPTIONS'].get()
    choice = variables['CHOICE'].get()
    print( "Generic Data" )
    print( f"  Scenario ID = {scen}" )
    print( f"  Integer Value = {intval}" )
    print( f"  Options = {opt}" )
    print( f"  Choice = {choice}" )

tk.Button( g_info, text="Save", command=save).grid(row=7, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code does not work properly. Firstly, I had to change the Save button row to 8 because it covers up the choice frame in row 7. But besides that, the entries made for the Scenario ID and and Integer Value are printed to the console, but the values for Options and Choice are blank.

Comment: Well, that's because of other mistakes you made.  You didn't hook the OPTIONS variable to the OptionMenu, and you didn't hook the CHOICE option to the Radiobutton.  I think you can see how to do the print, and how to hook it into your UI, which is what you asked.

Comment: No, I asked for advice on how to save the entries into a text file as in the example I gave below my code.  But instead of helping me, you decided to be a condescending jerk. Rather than correcting some errors in my code, you added more in and then told me to figure out the problem on my own. Thanks for nothing.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? From what I can see he has provided you with a `save` function to do exactly what you asked and all you have to do is replace the `print` method with the `write` method.

Comment: I have not been condescending in the slightest, although I certainly can be.  We're not here to write your code for you.  We're here to guide you to a result, and I have most definitely done exactly that.

Comment: Oh yes you have. I came here for some help with a library that I have never worked with before. But instead of offering me advice, you added errors to my code and then gave me a homework assignment. I was a math tutor in college, and that is not how I treated any of the students I worked with.